# Pandas timebased mean

Tags: python, pandas, influxdb

I have imported different data from homeassistant to influx db now I have it in a pandas dataframe and I would like to get the the mean() but it should be based on the time in the index.

I picked a small df to test and it looks like this:

```
                                   value
time                                   
2021-03-09 07:25:41.989791+00:00    0.0
2021-03-09 07:26:45.165453+00:00    0.0
2021-03-09 16:56:04.806150+00:00    1.0
2021-03-09 18:10:57.762609+00:00    0.0
2021-03-09 19:45:55.182860+00:00    1.0
2021-03-09 19:49:27.519186+00:00    0.0
```

So this is for example just my one of my lights at home. I would like to have the mean over time. So I can see how many % of the time it is turned on. When it says 1 it should be 1 until the next datapoint. In this df the mean should be very low because most of the time the light is turned off. It is only turned on between 16:56:04 to 18:10:57  and 19:45:55 to 19:49:27. So it is turned on approx: 1hour, 19minutes and the total recorded time 12 hours, 23 minutes. So the light was on for approx 10% of the recorded time.

There are another two problems:

1. I have sensors that have different values than 1 and 0 (for example temperature)

   2.the day will change.

I don't really know how to get started does anyone have a idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate durations for each value (`time_next` - `time`, then convert to seconds), and then take weighted average for each day:

```
# calculate durations
df['date'] = df['time'].dt.date
df['time_next'] = df['time'].shift(-1).ffill()
df['duration_s'] = (df['time_next'] - df['time']).dt.seconds

# calculate weighted average by date
df.groupby('date').apply(
    lambda z: np.average(z['value'], weights=z['duration_s']))
```

Output:

```
date
2021-03-09    0.105416
dtype: float64
```

P.S. Values can be any number, of course, not just binary

---

**Update:**

For correctly working with multi-day series we can alter the dataframe adding records for the end of each day (or the beginning of next day) with the last value seen on that day.

In the sample data in the original post, for example, that would be a `0` value at `2021-03-10 00:00:00`. This way duration for the last record of the day will show the amount of seconds remaining until the end of the day, making our weighted average calculate correctly.

Here is how it may be done in code (here I'm assuming `time` is the index of the original dataframe):

```
# add day-end values
z = df.append(
    df.resample('1d', label='right').last().ffill()
).sort_index()

# calculate durations
z['duration_s'] = -z.index.to_series().diff(-1).dt.total_seconds()

# calculate weighted average by date
z.groupby(z.index.date).apply(
    lambda z: np.average(z['value'], weights=z['duration_s'])).dropna()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer I really appreciate your help. So it works for me but I am trying to loop it for I think like 30 sensors and I get a "ZeroDivisionError: Weights sum to zero, can't be normalized". Is it because one day just has 0 values ? or is it because one day doesn't has values at all ? What If the light is turned on(1) on 2021-03-09 and turned off on 2021-03-11 ? Will 2021-03-10 be 0(off)?

Comment: @wieluk Yes, that is a good point. The error is likely due to zero weight in the weighted average leading to division by zero. This could have happened if you had only a single record for a day, in which case duration should be calculated from that event until the end of that day. Please see the Update section in my answer for a solution that should work correctly with these cases (and others that you mentioned, like days with no records)